# Building specific projects based on environment variables/shell output

Tags: svn, build, jenkins

I am currently using jenkins with svn and was wanting to build specific tags based on what a shell script I have on my server generates. The script will export a list of tag names that I want to build every five minutes; I was wanting jenkins to receive this list and then cycle through the list, building each of the tags.

I could only seem to get the parameterized build option to build a single revision and couldn't see how a list of builds could be processed. Should I be using the pre-build shell option? If so, how would I initiate a build for each tag generated by the script?

Essentially, I am looking for the best way to build the specific svn tags returned by my shell script in jenkins. Also, are env variables the best form for the list to be in for jenkins to receive as my script could easily be changed to conform to what ever format jenkins might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) may be able to iterate through a list of parameters (revision 2.12 claims something like that), but I'm not sure how to invoke it, so here are a couple of alternatives:

One solution is to create a build (the "Tag Builder") that takes a parameter that specifies the tag from which to build. Then create another build that uses your input file to launch builds of the Tag Builder using the [Jenkins Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). The master build would contain a shell build step that iterates through your input file and fetches a Jenkins url that initiates a job. The url on your Jenkins instance `http://jenkins:8080/job/MY_JOB/api` describes how to do so.

The downside of this solution is that it will become hard to extract the build trends for a specific tag since all tags are effectively in the same build. (This same downside would apply to the Parameterized Trigger solution as well.)

Depending on the lifetime of your tags, a better solution might be to use the Jenkins Remote API to create builds externally using your script and a template configuration. The url `http://jenkins:8080/api` describes how to create a job.